# Check for new messages on react native

Tags: react-native, setinterval

I'm doing a react native chat app. I'm having problems on the chatg screen to get the messages from other users...

```
this.intervalID = setInterval(() => {               
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });  
}, 1000);
```

Currently I have a setInterval every second to check for new messages, but that makes the app go really slow also the server is also suffering.

Is there a better way of doing that?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of polling for new messages, you should rather implement e.g. WebSockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking new message every second you can you [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v3) or another web socket service